# How to connect multiple Raspberry Pi to an Arduino

Tags: interface

If you want to make multiple Raspberry Pis to communicate with an Arduino, what interface can you use?

I have a sensor connected to an Arduino via I2C. Now I want to share the readings from the sensor with more than two Raspberry Pis. Each of the RPis will read the values and write them into a file. As long as I know you cannot use I2C or SPI, since the Raspberry Pis cannot be configured as I2c/SPI slave. Then what interface can you use?

I'm sorry that Raspberry Pi doesn't support I2C/SPI slave mode, though it must be useful.

Comment: Get an Ethernet shield and try a UDP broadcast (I think). Any number of other devices should be able to listen in then.

Comment: Or even via Serial, and have all the RPis receive the data, you just can't transmit back.

Comment: One way UART. Arduino broadcasts to all RPi's.